# sending mail by aspose

Tags: java, email, aspose

i try to send mail using aspose but the build for program is runing for along time then give me errorthis is my code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "kerolos", "MyPassword");
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.setFrom(new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com"));
    message.getTo().addMailAddress(new MailAddress("reciver@gmail.com"));
    message.setBody("nothinge");
    message.setSubject("me");
    client.send(message);
}
```

for sure i downloaded and import all libarar that i need 
this is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" class com.aspose.email.SmtpException: Failure   sending mail. ---> class com.aspose.email.SmtpException: The SMTP server  requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server  response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g73sm13415755wme.16 -  gsmtp

com.aspose.email.abk.f(SourceFile:49)
com.aspose.email.asu.n(SourceFile:130)
com.aspose.email.cg.a(SourceFile:311) 
com.aspose.email.internal.ah.h.a(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.email.internal.ah.j.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
com.aspose.email.SmtpClient.a(SourceFile:1982)
com.aspose.email.SmtpClient.send(SourceFile:1785) 
test.mina.main(mina.java:23)
at com.aspose.email.SmtpClient.a(SourceFile:1982)
at com.aspose.email.SmtpClient.send(SourceFile:1785)
at test.mina.main(mina.java:23)
Caused by: class com.aspose.email.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a     secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was:  5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g73sm13415755wme.16 - gsmtp

com.aspose.email.abk.f(SourceFile:49)
com.aspose.email.asu.n(SourceFile:130)
com.aspose.email.cg.a(SourceFile:311)
com.aspose.email.internal.ah.h.a(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.email.internal.ah.j.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at com.aspose.email.abk.f(SourceFile:49)
at com.aspose.email.asu.n(SourceFile:130)
at com.aspose.email.cg.a(SourceFile:311)
at com.aspose.email.internal.ah.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.aspose.email.internal.ah.j.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 35 seconds)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: this is code supose to send mail and this is the what soulde i say more

Comment: Did you read the error message?  Did you follow the link in the error message https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError  ?  You need to establish a TLS (encrypted) connection to use that port.

Comment: It looks like your client is not configure to use ssl correctly, try to put : `client.setSecurityOptions(SecurityOptions.Auto);`

Comment: i try this client.setSecurityOptions(SecurityOptions.Auto);  but it still give me the same error

Comment: You need to configure your google account to use weak security application or use an OAuth authentication system to send mail through Gmail's SMTP servers, according to this : [Allow less secure apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Comment: use i did it from along time ........

Comment: you can send email by this way:
http://javacigenclik.blogspot.com/2015/08/javada-mail-gondrmk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMail has strict rules for accessing emails by less secure applications. In order to allow GMail account to be accessed by less secure applications, you should enable the access by configuring your email account.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Please try it at your end and if the issue still persists, you can write to us on [Aspose.Email forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx) for further assistance.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.